# Is more suitable for my Django searching feature a DB-full-text or Haystack module?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search, django-haystack, xapian

I'm using Django with Python3 and Postgresql

1. I've read that Haystack uses Elastic Search (and I dislike Java), 
   but I see Xapian-Haystack doesn't work with Python3 (but I've heard about Xapian before and I think like it).
2. djorm-ext-pgfulltext is a database full text search module and I really don't know how is different from the previous option, in terms of efficiency.

(3. The option to build a simple search module would be the most inefficient, I believe.)

A list with the modules is displayed at:
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/search/

Comment: Could you please add more information about your goals?

Comment: Consider a website with articles, not intensive search, but I like to choose from the start the right solution. Maybe I'll need to learn search in the future, and I wouldn't like to waste time now doing something poorly.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you trying to find a best solution for full test search. But it depends. For example, it depends on size of your project.

I suggest to start with Postgres full text search. It quite good. Next option can be a sphinx search. 
And just after that use Elastic Search

Comment: Thank you, I think for the moment full text is simple enough.

Comment: Imho Xapian-Haystack does work with Python3.

Comment: I'd start with DB full text search (not least because support for that is coming to core in Django 1.10). If you need to move beyond that, the options will be dependent on what you're actually doing, what your data is like, your load, your deployment & ops considerations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - fulltext search with PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945141/django-fulltext-search-with-postgresql-and-elasticsearch)