# Django - fulltext search with PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch

Tags: django, postgresql, rest, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have a `Django` and `Django REST Framework` powered RESTful API (talking to a `PostgreSQL` DB backend) which supports filtering on a specific model.

Now I want to add a fulltext search functionality.

Is it be possible to use `Elasticsearch` for fulltext search and then apply my existing API filters on top of these search results?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you consider using **PostgreSQL** only to do what you asked for.

In my opinion it is the best solution because you will have the data and the search indexes directly inside *PostgreSQL* and you will not be forced to install and maintain additional software (such as *Elasticsearch*) and keep the data and indexes in sync.

This is the simplest code example you can have to perform a [full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+postgresql+full-text-search) in Django with PostgreSQL:

```
Entry.objects.filter(body_text__search='Cheese')
```

For all the basic **documentation** on using the [full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+postgresql+full-text-search) in Django with PostgreSQL you can use the official documentation: **"[Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)"**

If you want to deepen further you can read an **article** that I wrote on the subject:

**"[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](http://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql)"**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad to be answered with code, but it's definitely possible.

You can easily search your elasticsearch for rows matching your full-text criteria.

Then get those rows' PK fields (or any other candidate key, used to uniquely identify rows in your PostgreSQL dB), and filter your django ORM-backed models for PKs matching those you found from your Elasticsearch.

Pseudocode would be:

```
def get_chunk(l, length):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), length):
        yield l[i:i + length]

res = es.search(index="index", body={"query": {"match": ...}})

pks = []
for hit in res['hits']:
    pks.append(hit['pk'])

for chunk_10k in get_chunk(pks, 10000):
    DjangoModel.objects.filter(pk__in=chunk_10k, **the_rest_of_your_api_filters)
```

EDIT
To resolve a case in which lots and lots of PKs might be found with your elastic query, you can define a generator that yields successive 10K rows of the results, so you won't step over your DB query limit and to ensure best update performance. I've defined it above with a function called `get_chunk`.

Something like that would work for alternatives like redis, mongodb, etc ...

Comment: Yeah, this can be a solution. Potentially problematic, though. For example if the search returns thousands of results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009706/postgresql-max-number-of-parameters-in-in-clause.

Comment: @dm295 the first of a long series of problematic issue with Elasticsearch.

Comment: @dm295 of course. You should have a means of chunking requests of more than n-K pks in your postgresql DB. I had the same requirement for MongoDB and found that __in queries with a chunk of 10K~50K yield-ed the best performance. Also MongoDB had it's own limitation of 16Mbs for each query, so in many cases, doing a vanilla __in would have resulted in failure. It's easy to do and I'll do an edit just in case.

Comment: @DušanMaďar I stumbled across this question today and figured you didn't have any feedback on it. Did you find a better solution? It'd be perfect if you could share any solution you might have ended up implementing better than this (without like ditching postgresql or ...) Thanks

Comment: @SpiXel basically we went with ES only search and had to rewrite filters, etc. to work with ES.