# How can I use elasticsearch in my django Project?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, elasticsearch, web

I'm working on a search bar in my site made with django . I want to include elasticsearch while I already have saved my data in postgresql. what should I do to connect elasticsearch with my django application and postgresql ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a full blown elasticsearch server isn't what you need since postgresql has a built in full text search feature. Here is a djangocon talk which covers some of the options and tradeoffs:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=is3R8d420D4&t=187s

If you still choose to use elastic you might want to take a look at [Django Elasticsearch DSL](https://github.com/django-es/django-elasticsearch-dsl). It will allow you to index your models in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

We already have a post discussing the similar scenario. Please, have a look into -
[Django - fulltext search with PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945141/django-fulltext-search-with-postgresql-and-elasticsearch)